# takes the sub strings from string

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I try to write a code in scheme functional programming, that takes the sub strings from one string.

```
input "HelloWorld" output "Hello"+"World"
input "TheTreeIsGreen" output "The"+"Tree"+"Is"+"Green"
```

any help?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, show some effort from your part. You can't post here a homework and expect people to solve it for you, if you don't show first a real attempt to solve the question by yourself

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be easily solved by means of regular expressions. For example, in Racket:

```
(regexp-match* #rx"[A-Z][a-z]+" "TheTreeIsGreen")
=> '("The" "Tree" "Is" "Green")
```

Comment: Racket actually has `regexp-split` for this exact purpose.

Comment: @Maxwell it won't work with `regexp-split`, give it a try and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You have schooled me as usual, Oscar. I always learn from you!

Comment: thanks but i want a recursive way to do that, by using strings or lists

Comment: @user1839201 ok, but post in the question first the code you've written so far.

Comment: i'm new in scheme but i think to use string-ref and string-append

Comment: @Maxwell it's because it will only match the first thing that matches I think. regexp-match* will match everything. There should be a regexp-split* I think

Comment: @Wes No, regexp-split will split everything by a regex. The problem is it that the string you split by is not included in the results. Thus, regexp-match* is the way to go. Try it yourself so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Maxwell, okay, but regexp-match wouldn't work either >.>